# Xamarin XAML designer dose not update any of the transfrom data

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The XAML designer is not updating any of the transform values like rotation, translation, etc. It works fine otherwise, it also worker before, it just stopped working suddenly and I don't know what I did.

```
<Ellipse />
<Rectangle WidthRequest="5" AnchorX="0.5" AnchorY="0.8" TranslationY="-40" Fill="Black" />
<Rectangle AnchorX="0.5" AnchorY="0.8" TranslationY="-40" />
```

In the above code I used the Translation its not reflecting only in the designer, but if I run the app its updated.

[image: That's what its look like in the designer]

That's what its look like in the designer.

[image: That's what its should look]

That's what its looks in the output when I run the application, its not reflecting in the XAML designer. So I have to run application every time I need see the result of any update when I use any kind of transform effect.

Comment: no code snippet or anything, how are we supposed to reply.

Comment: sorry my bad, there I updated with the code

Comment: Try tp restart your VS. If the XAML designer does not work everytime with this project or the new project, you could try to repair the VS.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thanks, repairing the VS solved the problem.

Comment: I have posted the comment in reply. You could accept as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart your VS. If the XAML designer does not work everytime with this project or the new project, you could try to repair the VS.